# What are the equivalent of the following Java APIs in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to compile a java program with GWT, but the program use several APIs that are not supported by GWT. What are the equivalents of these in GWT?

```
java.util.UUID
java.io.PrintWriter
java.util.concurrent.*
java.lang.ThreadLocal
java.lang.ref.WeakReference
java.net.URI
```

Comment: If they are not supported, they are not supported. End of story.

Comment: Looks like you are doing a lot of Business logic on UI, Why dont you delegate those to Servlets?

Comment: This is supposed to be a client-only game app , no server required

Comment: @user1615898 IF it is client-only app, then You don't need ThreadLocal and concurrent stuff (as JS is single-threaded), You don't need PrintWriter, and probably others as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### java.util.UUID

This is hard to emulate well, for at least two reasons the spec asks for 100s of nanoseconds (browsers only do up to milliseconds, and that is coarse to avoid some attacks), and requirements for a "node" don't really make sense in a browser. Emulation does exist, but knowing that the code you wish to use needs UUID would make me want to understand the tradeoffs before picking one, to make sure you aren't causing later issues.

The gwt documentation actually calls out UUID as a class that you might want to add your own emulation for: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html. It isn't terribly easy, but it isn't really hard either, just takes some work to get set up right.

### java.io.PrintWriter

On the one hand, I know of no emulation for this, but on the other hand it wouldn't be very hard to write - mostly the incoming strings would need to get delegated to some underlying Writer, which also isn't emulated. I assume this is for logging of some kind? Might make sense to only very roughly emulate it and either throw it away (like PrintStream in existing GWT), or explain a little more, see if it can't be purpose built for what you need.

### java.util.concurrent.*

GWT compiles Java to JS, and JS is inherently singly threaded, so these classes don't make a ton of sense in GWT. That said, the Guava-GWT project provides emulation for several of these, and if you are missing any, they are very simple to write the leftover ones.

### java.lang.ThreadLocal

I haven't seen this emulated before, but as above, this would be incredibly simple to write your own emulation for - just treat it like a wrapper for the object, since the browser only has one thread anyway.

### java.lang.ref.WeakReference

Here is a problem for JS - the runtime simply doesn't support this concept. Even modern JS with WeakMap and WeakSet can't deal with this, they are very simple versions of the concept that we're used to in Java. This is the only item in your list that at this time is not possible, from what I know of the browser.

### java.net.URI

While this is a big class, it should be reasonable to emulate this, depending on exactly what you are going to do next - for example, `toURL()` and then `openConnection()` isn't going to work, but if you are just using this as a simple builder for URL objects, it looks a lot like the (relatively new) URL object in the browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.